# How to get builds badge image from Gitlab CI

Tags: build, gitlab, badge, gitlab-ci

I would like to get the build badge image on my project from Gitlab CI. I know the url ([documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ci/quick_start/README.html#sts=Builds%20badge)) :

> http://example.gitlab.com/namespace/project/badges/branch/build.svg

But my project is a private project, and the link require authentification and I don't know how to be authenticated with this url.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Strangely the linked documentation page does not mention the image link (anymore?). The URL still follows the format `domain.com/{user or group}/{repo name}/badges/{branch}/build.svg`

Comment: @boxama Thank you!  Why does the GitLab documentation have to make it so hard... it doesn't answer the simple question 'How do I get a build status badge?'.  You did :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project/repository's `README.md` should be able to show your badge as it's already in an authenticated session with your/the Gitlab server. If your trying to show the badge on a different, non-Gitlab page on the same server, you could symlink the build.svg to a location in your www root and ensure that your other webserver to follow symlinks.